# Sending Email Attachment in Background in swift 2

Tags: ios, background, swift2, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am working on the sending mail to the user when we click on the submit button.But we should not use the MFMailComposeViewController.I want to send it in backgorund.
Can anyone help me to solve this issue.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: https://sendgrid.com/blog/send-email-in-ios-with-new-sendgrid-library/

Comment: You can not sent mail using MFMaillComposerViewController in background. You can do using other librarary like SKPSMTP Library or , you can use sendgrid as @Shubhank gave link.

Comment: you cant send the mail internally because iphone  application mailcomposer to acess  mail or to send mail

Comment: @meera in skpsmtp iam getting the error like "cannot connect to server"